# Wordpress multi language site

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I have a project with WordPress for a multi-language, multi-country site.
i want to have a URL structure like:

- domainname.com (Main site) (English)
- fr.domainname.com (French)
- ko.domainname.com (Korean)

Also i don't want a URL structure like:

- domainname.com/fr
- domainname.com/ko

i need to make it for 20 languages.. Seems WPML & Multilanguage by BestWebSoft Plugins will do translation well but with domainname/fr structure..

To achive my needed url structure,  i must want to create 20 subdomains for 20 languages? also i want to keep 20 different wordpress sites for each language? Or any simple way is there?  Looking forward Your Replies, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With WPML this is no problem. You can opt for subdomains per language instead of directories or ?lang=xx.

In the Hosting administration, add the language sub-domains and point them to the directory with your wordpress setup (eg /public_html).

You will only have one Wordpress setup running, no matter how many languages.